# How to launch js code before attached event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line

```
<input type="button" value="Checkout »" class="checkout" onclick="addtocart();">
```

How can I launch code before the `addtocard()` function runs and disable the event when I need ?

What I mean and what I'm trying to do

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var btn = $('.checkout');
 var clickhandler = btn.onclick;

 if ( $('.checkout').length ) {
        btn.onclick = null; 
 }

 $('.checkout').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var os = $('select[name="configoption[2]"]').val();
  var cpanel = $('select[name="configoption[5]"').val();

  if ( cpanel == 70 && os != 28 ) {
   alert("You selected to install cpanel control panel, cpanel required the centos 7 x64 operating system");
   return false;
  }


  console.log( 'all good' );
  btn.click(clickhandler);

 });
  
    function addtocart() {
       alert('dont want to get here without validate'); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Checkout »" class="checkout" onclick="addtocart();">
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just remove the `onclick` attribute from the element and call `addtocart()` from the click binding after the validation?

Comment: Yes. What @ReinS says. Inline `onclick=someJavascript()` in this day and age is terrible. Avoid it and instead attach handlers.

Comment: Hi, It not something I write. I'm trying to change something on read php application that update each time and some time come encoded.

Comment: I am confused about what your last comment. Can you explain with more detail?

Comment: I want to change the above in WHMCS php application. In the checkout page I added two fields with a module and I want to validate them when user press the checkout button. If failed to hold the onclick function attached from trigger and go to the next page, but if validate success continue regular. All the validate in jquery I wrote. By the way my code work but the event still take to the next page.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach the issue.

- Seperate the calls
- Make validate its own function
- Keep AddToCart

```js
function ValidateStuff() {
    var retVal = false;
    if( $('.isVal').prop('checked') == true) {
           retVal = true;
        }
    return retVal;
}
  
function checkout() {
    if( ValidateStuff()) {
          addtocart();
        } else {
          alert("No cart for you. Check entries..");
        }
    }
  
    function addtocart() {
       alert('We have validated and now add to cart'); 
    }

$( "body" ).on( "click", ".checkout", function() {
      checkout();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Checkout »" class="checkout">

<input id="chkVal" class="isVal" type="checkbox" checked/>
<label class="isVal" for="chkVal">Click to simulate valid form</label>
</br>
```

Comment: Hi, It not something I write. I'm trying to change something on ready php application that update each time and some time come encoded.